# Using JOIN inside relation

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables: Tournaments, Participants, Users. The structure is:

*Tournaments:*

```
-Id
-Description
-Date
```

*Participants*

```
-Id
-Id_tourn
-Id_user
```

*Users*

```
-Id
-Name
```

On my blade template I need all the info from Tournaments table and info of the User which is the participant of that tournament.

I've created the relation between Tournaments and User Models.

UPDATE:
Tournaments Model:

```
public function users() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'Participants', 'Id_tourn', 'Id_user');
}

public function getTournaments()
{
    return $this->with('users')->get();
}
```

Tournament Controller:

```
public function show()
{
    $tourns = new Tournaments();

    $tournaments = $tourns->getTournaments();
    return $tournaments;
}
```

but when I try `$tournament->users` in foreach loop it returns 0 results

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the difference between a participant and a user here?

Comment: `participants` looks like a pivot between `users` and `tournaments`, which you generally don't have a model/relationship for. You'd just do `$tournament->user->name` (although you'd like have to do that in a loop, `$tournament->users AS $user`, `$user-name`)

Comment: @Devon, participants table doesn't include user info, it just contents which user is taking part in tournament

Comment: @TimLewis, I've tried to use hasManyThrought, but as you see, I have four different column names: Id(Tournament.Id), Id_tourn(Participants.Id_tourn), Id_user(Participants.Id_user) and Id(Users.Id). 
hasManyThrought() doesn't know how to work with four different named columns.

Comment: `users.id`, `tournaments.id`, `users_tournaments.user_id` and `users_tournaments.tournament_id` would be a normal many-to-many relationship between `users` and `tournaments`. Table name could be `participants`, but I'm not sure why you would need a `participants` model.

Comment: @TimLewis, I've updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: The answer below is saying basically what I am; `participants` is the pivot between `users` and `tournaments`, where `participants.tournament_id` references `tournaments.id`, and `participants.user_id` references `users.id`. Then you use `$tournament->users()->attach($user->id)`, or `$user->tournaments()->attach($tournament->id)` to connect em all. Add some pivot data if you need it using `->withPivot([...]);`. All referenced in the Documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using a One to Many relationship on a Many to Many case, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) are the documentation of the Many to Many relationship. You need to make a relationship like this:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'Participants', 'Id_tourn', 'Id_user');
}
```

So you will can access users like this:

```
$tournament->users
```

Comment: Unfortunately, $tournament->users is empty in that way

Comment: The problem is that I need to have the fifth argument in belongsToMany() function as I need somehow to connect Tournaments.Id and Participants.Id_tourn. But this function doesn't provide that opportunity.

Comment: You dont need another argument to this, the belongsToMany third argument is the participants colum that references the primary key of tournaments, and the fourth argument is the participants colum that references the primary key of users. In documentation it says "is the foreign key name", are you using foreign keys on the pivot table (Participants)? I'm not sure it is necessary.

Comment: Now, it's clear about belongsToMany() arguments, thanks, but unfortunately it returns 0 users, I don't know why

Comment: Can you update the question with your current relationship and the code where you are using it?